# Mind boggling Function for Looping

Tags: javascript

If there's anyone who can help me understand this one, I will be impressed. It's #28 from [John Resig's advanced JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#28).

Here's a function for looping, and, if you look at the tutorial, it seems to run 3 times producing the 6 Pass below.

Can you please explain in plain language in as much detail as possible what is happening in this program, explaining along the way:

1. `fn.call(array, array[i], i)`  Why are there these 3 parameters to the function and how do they all work. Does the function first deal with array, then array[i], and then i? What's happening when all that is going on?
2. Also, in the function, I understand that `i++` goes up every time that it goes through the array.length, but what triggers `num++` to increase it's value, and in what way is `value == num++`
3. In `function(value, i)`, what is `value`? Is value alternately 0,1,2 of the loop array? If so, how do those loop array numbers get passed as a parameter in `function(value, i)`
4. `this instanceof Array`  what is this trying to show?  How?.

Code:

```
function loop(array, fn){ 
  for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) 
    fn.call( array, array[i], i ); 
} 
var num = 0; 
loop([0, 1, 2], function(value, i){ 
  assert(value == num++, "Make sure the contents are as we expect it."); 
  assert(this instanceof Array, "The context should be the full array."); 
});
```

> PASS Make sure the contents are as we expect it.
> PASS The context should be the full array.  
> PASS Make sure the contents are as we expect it. 
>  
> PASS The context should be the full array.  
> PASS Make sure the contents are as we expect it. 
>  
> PASS The context should be the full array.

Comment: p.s. Very cool that you are reading up on this stuff, javascript is extremely fun when you get into the advanced concepts like these :)

Comment: @Mike Lewis, thanks it`s fascinating. I`m asking you a question under your answer if you don`t mind.

Comment: your using -->**`** instead of a single quote...thats why your question was so badly formatted.

Comment: @giddy thanks. I have ' and ` on my Japanese keyboard, get them confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `function` is an anonymous function, that is, a function without a name.  The full second argument to `loop` is

```
function(value, i) {
  assert(value == num++, "Make sure the contents are as we expect it.");
  assert(this instanceOf Array, "The context should be the full array.");
}
```

which is a complete anonymous function which takes three arguments:  `this` (the object for which it is a method), the current value, and the loop counter.

`loop` iterates over the array, and uses `fn.call` to invoke the anonymous function, passing it three arguments; here, the array object must be explicit, because `call` can't know what context the function reference it's being invoked on should be invoked in (that is, what to make `this` in the call).

The anonymous function, as invoked by `loop`, receives the array as `this`.  The second `ASSERT` verifies this.  It also expects that the array's value is `[0, 1, 2]` and verifies this by incrementing `num` on each call and comparing that to the passed array element.

So, following the execution chain:

1. `num` is declared and initialized to 0.
2. `loop([0, 1, 2], function ...)` is invoked.
3. `loop` invokes `fn`, the anonymous function, with the array (as `this`), its first element, and `i` which indicates the element offset.  (`i` is never actually used.)
4. The anonymous function `ASSERT`s that it was passed the expected first element, 0, by comparing against `num` and incrementing `num` afterward.
5. The anonymous function `ASSERT`s that its `this` is an `Array`.
6. `loop` invokes `fn` as in #3, but with the second array element.
7. The anonymous function again performs its `ASSERT`s, this time comparing the passed second array element, which is expected to be 1, against `num` (which, because of the post-increment in step 4, is 1).
8. `loop` invokes `fn` as before with the third array element.
9. The anonymous function does its `ASSERT`s again, this time comparing the expected array element 2 against `num` whose value is now 2.

Comment: thank you very much. There`s a couple things I`d be grateful you would explain a little more. First.you say "call can`t know what context the function reference it`s being invoked on should be invoked in (that is, what tomake this in the call)". If array wasn`t explicit, then wouldn`t "this" just be global context and why wouldn`t that work.  Second,you say the anonymous function receives the array as "this." why wouldn`t "this" be passed in as a parameter to make it function(this, value, i)  Third, what do you mean "element offset" and why is that important.

Comment: The anonymous function is an object method.  In methods, `this` is a reference to the object.  As such, it has to be specified explicitly when called; normally, this would be done directly as `array.method`, but when using the `call` method on a function object it's necessary to specify the object (`this`) as an explicit parameter.  "Global context" might work in general, but the anonymous function is written to expect `this` to be an array.  The key point here is that the anonymous function expects to be an `Array` method, so `call` needs to provide an `Array`. (more)

Comment: The array offset isn't in fact important here (as I noted, it's not actually used anywhere).  `loop` is looping over the elements of the array "the hard way", by defining `i` as 0 and then incrementing it while it's less than the length of `array`.  `[0, 1, 2]` has three elements, so `fn` is invoked with element 0 and its offset from the start of `array` 0, then element 1 and its offset 1, then element 2 and its offset 2.

Comment: regarding "the anonymous function expects it to be an Array," this is only because it tries to assert that it is an instanceof Array, correct? if they weren`t testing "instanceof Array," is there another way that the anonymous function would expect it to be an array? does the fact that "value" of the array is passed as a parameter somehow tell the function it is dealing with an array?

Comment: No, the "array-ness" is not otherwise visible.  I *think* the point of the example was showing how to create an anonymous object method (of `Array` in this case), as opposed to simply an anonymous function.  If so, arguably it's missing an aspect (which may have been there originally):  `ASSERT(this[i] == value, "The array element belongs to this array.");` or similar.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your help. your explanation was very clear.

Answer (score 2):

fn is a function pointer to the anonymous function that was created when invoking loop.

a) There are three parameters because the first one is a reference to the object you are going to be acting on, i.e. the array, the 2nd parameter is just current value in the iteration of the array, and the third value is location of that element in that array.

b) when you call num++, it increments the value of num. The post increment returns the value (aka assigns to value) and then increments num.

c) value is the 2nd parameter passed in by fn.call a couple lines up.

d) **this** refers to the array that you passed into the first parmater in your fn.call() invocation.

Comment: regarding (a), what does it mean when you say "reference to the object you are going to be acting on." what happens when a function is acting on an object, vs, when it is not acting on an object? or do they always act on an object? regarding (d), if this refers to the array that was a parameter, why didn`t the anonymous function say function(this, value, i) instead of just function(value, i)?

Answer (score 2):

I think an easier way to understand what's going on is to remove the usage of `call` and instead invoke the method directly - the old fashioned way.

```
function loop(array, fn) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        fn(array[i], i);
}

var num = 0;
loop([0, 1, 2], function(value, i) {
    assert(value == num, "Make sure the contents are as we expect it.");
    assert(this instanceof Array, "The context should be the full array.");
    num++;
});
```

If you run this code on the source [url](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#28), you would see the `this instanceof Array` test fails each time, since `this` is not pointing to an instance of Array anymore.

To make `this` point to an instance of Array, we need to invoke the method using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply).

```
fn.call(array, array[i], i);
```

The first parameter is what `this` will point to. All other parameters here are passed as arguments to the function being called. Note that we can cheat here to pass the test. Instead of passing **the** `array` object that we are looping over, you can pass **any** Array object to make the second test pass.

```
fn.call([], array[i], i);
fn.call([1,2,3,4,5], array[i], i);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually know javascript but I believe I understand whats going on...

The first four lines are defining a function called loop.  Loop takes in two variables, an array and a function.  The only reason why I believe the second parameter is function is because the coder called call on the variable which probably calls the function.  The function loops through the elements of the array and passes them to the function somehow through the call method.  You should probably look this part up.

After the definition, num is defined to start at zero.

Then comes the fun part.  The function loop is called with the parameters [0, 1, 2] and an anonymous function that was created on the spot. function(value, i) and everything after it is the definition of this anonymous function.  It has no name but it just defined for this function call.  The function checks to make sure that value equals num and increments num after it and then checks to makes sure the variable is an array.